# Can I change my 2011 iMac's graphic card from AMD's to nvidia Quadro?

Tags: video-editing, gpu

I do lot of video editing work, mostly on FCP & Avid and I feel Quadro card is way to go.
Do you think I can get it changed from Apple?

-Reddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't even think the hardware would be compatible. Quite frankly, while you can open up the system and tinker with it, you have to worry about two things:

1. Form factor - The card is probably a different shape. Apple partners with other companies when designing a system and the fact that they put an ATI in there says something about the engineering of the machine.
2. Power & bus interface - These are likely less of an issue, but something to be aware of.

The iMac is a turnkey system, not an upgradable machine, like the Mac Pro (or, *gasp*, a PC). I'm sorry that this is not the answer you want to hear, but I don't think that Apple will do it. That said, it can't hurt to ask.

Comment: They will say no. That is all.

Comment: My instinct says Apple would not respond to my questions as they have no option for graphic cards other than 2 AMD models. Guess I should stick to stock cards. Thanks anyway Mosche.

Answer (score 0):

Some cards can be made to work in OS X with custom ROM, however, OS X extensions do not support the card's hardwired device ID, so it would result in a Kernel Panic at boot. If the card is close to another officially supported card in OS X or use the same GPU, there's an easy hack which will allow it to operate in OS X.

#### NVIDIA Quadro 4

This card is very close to GeForce 4 Ti series, using same GPU and PCB layout. Some even have dual DVI outputs.

Custom GeForce 4 Ti ROM will make the card work as a Mac Card, but a Kernel Panic will happen every time you try to boot with original NVIDIA extensions.

To begin you'll need to:

- find the hardware Device ID of your card
- have your card flashed and working with a Mac ROM, you can test your card in OS 9 (currently available ROM for Quadro 4 700 XGL)
- have an editor capable of modifying plist files.

For the Quadro 4 700 XGL

- Device ID of the card is 025B (Quadro 4 700 XGL) 10DE (NVIDIA)
- ROM is available online
- Quadro 4 / GeForce 4 Ti series will use 2 OS X extensions to operate.  First is `NVDAResman.kext` (used by every NVIDIA card), second is `NVDANV20Hal.kext` (specific kernel extension for GeForce 4 series / NV2x GPUs)

---

#### Before physically installing your Mac flashed card, let's proceed with the Extensions hack.

1. Go to your root disk (OS X installation) and go to folder `/System/Library/Extensions`
2. Back up the extensions you're going to modify (here `NVDAResman.kext` and `NVDANV20Hal.kext`). Keep one copy of each in a safe place, and one copy of each in your desktop. Last 2 copies are going to be edited.
3. Right-Click on the first extension you copied on your desktop and use "show package content" option. The extension will open as a classic folder.
4. Open the "Contents" folder and Open the file Info.plist with your editor.
5. Search for string `IOPCIMatch` and add your card's device ID.  Save the file and proceed to do the same with the second extension.

[image]

6. Copy the edited extensions packages to `/System/Library/Extensions`
7. Open the Disk Utility application and run the repair permissions utility on your drive.
8. Now install the card, and reboot your computer.

[image]

Credit: http://themacelite.wikidot.com/kext-mod