# How to keep two Macs in sync?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, osx-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Completely synchronise multiple Macs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42911/completely-synchronise-multiple-macs)

I've got a MacBook Pro and a Mac Mini, and I want to keep them in sync: all files and folders, all settings, all everything.

Here's what I know won't work: Dropbox, iCloud.

Here's what I know might work: install Mountain Lion Server on the Mac Mini as my "main" computer in an admin account, then use that to create a separate network account / portable home directory / mobile users / something like that, then make that account the default one on my MacBook Pro.

The problem is that I have absolutely no clue how to do this and I'd like to get some help.

I'm aware that I may have to use a few different things to do the full sync - like setting up OS X server to do most of the work, but still using Dropbox for certain files and something like Chronosync for others.

Please tell me where to start.

Comment: How do you want to handle settings which *must* be different on the two Macs (e.g. window size preferences, Mail states etc.)? It's probably better to use Dropbox to sync documents etc. and keep the rest local

Comment: Might be relevant: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5338

Comment: Hi patrix, thanks for helping me clarify what I'm trying to do. The way I see it is that the Mac Mini will be the main computer / server where everything lives and to/from which it will all get backed up, and the MacBook Pro will be the client where I do a lot of my actual work. That's why I initially was attracted to the Mountain Lion Server with network accounts idea. I have been keeping most things local and syncing some documents via Dropbox for a while, but it's not been working the way I like - I want a much tighter and more complete sync than that.

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks - I did I actually see that very same knowledgebase article. I agree that it might be relevant. But I can not tell from reading through it if it's actually going to do what I want. Also, it's written from the perspective that presumes that I've already got the server and network accounts configuration running adequately, but I don't, and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing as http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42911/completely-synchronise-multiple-macs - the only difference is that he trying to do it with Snow Leopard and I'm doing it with Mountain Lion. There have been some changes to the OS X server package in the last few iterations that may include major functional evolutions and may just mean different names on a lot of the same features. It's hard for me to tell exactly what's different and what's the same from when that guy asked the question years ago. That's why I asked it again now.

Comment: I'm very disappointed that this question has been closed as a duplicate. After it was marked as a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42911/completely-synchronise-multiple-macs, I explained very clearly that, while the nature of the problem is quite the same, the solutions to it are different due to the time that has passed and changes to the relevant software, not to mention additional software options that would not have been available at the time of the previous question and its answers...

Comment: For example, one of the answers says that "Apples Offial name [for mobile accounts] is Portable Home Directories..." but in the link he gives, the term "Portable Home Directories" appears nowhere. That's because Apple has changed the name. Therefore, those directions are not helpful for someone who's approaching this issue in late 2012 / early 2013 as opposed to mid 2011. I would like this question please to be reopened so I can seek an actual answer that will work with Mountain Lion Server, not an earlier version for Snow Leopard or Lion.

Comment: Moreover, I think the three of you who closed it should know that you've inconvenienced me and done me a disservice, as I'm specifically looking to set this up soon and came here to get guidance on how to do it. You may think you're doing cleanup, but actually you are obstructing me effort to work on an interesting project.

Comment: @gesher it's been almost a year. I'm looking to do the exact same thing. Any further developments?

Comment: Hi @MattTagg. As you can see, this question was marked as a duplicate by patrix, bassplayer7 and bmike. This prevented it from being answered. I did try explaining to them why it was not  a duplicate, but they were not interested in helping me get an answer to my problem. As an alternative, I recommend posting this question on Quora. If you post it there and contact me (my name there is Natan Gesher), I'll be happy to use some of my credits to promote it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Carbon Copy Cloner (http://www.bombich.com)? it has a sync feature that may help you.

Comment: The asker is looking for a specific syncing solution. While CCC may have features which could be of use here, it would help if you could elaborate a bit more on how the application could support a syncing workflow.

Comment: Hi yorch, thanks for the idea. I have used CCC for backup and restore, but I am not really sure that it would work for what I'm trying to do, which is keep two computers in sync all the time. But I did just ask this question over there, to find out if they have any ideas: http://help.bombich.com/discussions/questions/19736-can-i-use-ccc-to-sync-everything-on-two-macs-all-the-time.