# Install a graphics card in a MacBook Pro 2015

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, upgrade, gpu

If I buy the $1900 MacBook Pro, would it be possible to buy the AMD graphics card separately, and install it myself? I can't afford the $2499 MacBook Pro but really need a new MacBook Pro.

Comment: @Mahmud Assamaray, Do yourself a favor, save your money until you have enough to purchase the higher end model as everything is then covered under warranty.  The last thing I'd be doing with a brand new MacBook Pro is opening it up to  save a little bit of money upgrading the SSD.

Comment: @Mahmud: What you might save in upgrading the SSD yourself (maybe 100$?), you will lose in warranty, time doing the upgrade and reinstalling the OS, and probably resale value. However, your question was with regard to the GPU, and my statement still holds true for that piece. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42907/replace-or-add-graphic-card-on-macbook-pro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Apple portables do not have user-upgradeable graphics boards.  The graphics chips are integrated into the main logic board and cannot be removed or replaced.