# Can I use external graphic card with MacBook Pro?

Tags: gpu

I have a MacBook Pro Retina display late 2013.

processor  = 2ghz Intel core i7
memory     = 8GB
os         = Mavericks 10.9.2
graphic    = 1GB Intel graphic card

Can I use any external graphic card as we use an external hard disk?

Comment: [See answer here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/191622/65956)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do so, you might want to check this article: http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/162652-diy-external-thunderbolt-gpu-turbo-charges-macbook-air-graphics-performance-by-7x

As for a regular user I can say that there is no way yet to use external gpu.